# Cloud ML model prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have deployed tensorflow saved Model in cloud ML for text classification with the following,

```
    input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_x:0')
    keep_prob = graph.get_tensor_by_name('keep_prob:0')
    predictions = graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax/predictions:0')

feed_dict = {input_x: x_test, batch_size: 8, sequence_length: x_lengths,  keep_prob: 1.0}
```

Its deployed no error. I have a csv file to predict. 
--csv file--

```
"the test is completed"
"the test2 is done"
```

Getting only errors.
How to convert this to json for the model I trained, to batch predict in cloud ML??

saved_model_cli - Info

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['batch_size'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: ()
        name: batch_size:0
    inputs['input_x'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 25)
        name: input_x:0
    inputs['keep_prob'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: ()
        name: keep_prob:0
    inputs['sequence_length'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1)
        name: sequence_length:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['predictions'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: softmax/predictions:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Currently i converted the csv to Json, used to predict:

```
{"sequence_length": 25, "batch_size": 1, "keep_prob": 1.0, "input_x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 16, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 20]}
```

Exception:

```
 Exception during running the graph: Cannot feed value of shape (1,) for Tensor u\'keep_prob:0\', which has shape \'()\' (Error code: 2)\n'
```

Comment: Can you run `saved_model_cli show --all --dir /path/to/model` and provide the output?

Comment: @rhaertel80 added the saved_model_cli, check the update question.

Answer (score 2):

This model appears to need several changes to be directly servable. One requirement of the service is that each of the inputs have an unspecified outer dimension which is interpreted as the "batch" dimension. The inputs `input_x` and `sequence_length` meet this requirement, but `batch_size` and `keep_prob` do not.

The service dynamically builds batches which is why it needs to be variable length. Thus, have an input called `batch_size` is going to be problematic, since the service doesn't know that it should be setting that input. Instead, it builds up a batch and sends it to TensorFlow. TensorFlow already knows the batch size because it's the value of the outer dimension of inputs such as `input_x`.

Instead of using `batch_size` as an input, it's preferable to do something like:

```
batch_size = tf.shape(input_x)[0]
```

Although I will note that even the need for that is usually fairly rare in practice. Things usually "just work", because `input_x` is used in some sort of operation like a matrix multiply or convolution which will handle things fine without explicitly knowing the batch size.

Finally, there is `keep_prob`, which usually indicates there is a dropout layer in the model. Even though you can hard code this to 1.0, it's usually recommended that you just remove dropout layers altogether for serving. Basically, when you export the model, you actually build a *different* graph than for training. This is exemplified in [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/b76329111ea7b1545bfbba9f603cf96c61bbb75c/flowers/trainer/model.py#L265).